# Getting error on Content Editor after upgrading to Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have done an upgrade from **Sitecore 7.5** to **Sitecore 8**, And I am getting **an error** when trying to Access the Content Editor.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator
>
> **Source Error:**  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator]
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrIndexParameters..ctor(IIndexValueFormatter >valueFormatter, IFieldQueryTranslatorMap`1 fieldQueryTranslators, >FieldNameTranslator fieldNameTranslator, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts, >IFieldMapReaders fieldMap, Boolean convertQueryDatesToUtc) +310
>
> > Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1..ctor(SolrSearchContext >context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts) +192
> >     Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchContext.GetQueryable(IExecutionCo>ntext[] executionContexts) +83
> >       Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.TestingSearch.GetRunningTests() +637
> >      Sitecore.ContentTesting.Data.SitecoreContentTestStore.GetActiveTests(DataUri >hostItemDataUri, String searchText) +252
> >     Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.GetContentTestingWar>nings.Process(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args) +247
> >       (Object , Object[] ) +141
> >       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
> >       Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.GetWarnings(Boolean >hasSections) +271
> >     Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArg>s args, Control parent) +178
> >     Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item >item, Item root, Control parent, Boolean showEditor) +231
> >     Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item >folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor) +374
> >       Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +411
> >     Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(Even>tArgs e) +212

Comment: `Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.` — could you please provide the stack trace?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, Please find the updated question.

Comment: What is your intended indexing engine? Is it Lucene or SOLR?

Comment: Our Indexing Engine is Solr

Comment: Have you disabled all Lucene configs?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko , Yes

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that you already disabled all the **Lucene** configuration under your *App_Config > Include folder* and read the [Sitecore Search Scaling Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_search_scaling%20guide_sc7-a4.pdf) chapter 3, if not yet, please do so.

Now, the problem relies on your Global.asax, replace the:

```
Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application"
```

To:

```
Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication"
```

This is assuming **again** that your dependency injection is the *CastleWindsor* and all the essential DLLs for CastleWindors were deployed in your web instance (*Website > bin folder*)

These are:

- SolrNet.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
- Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration.dll
- Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.dll

Alternatively, there are other four (4) DI framework you can check if CastleWindor is not the dependency injection of your project, and the descriptive details of these DI can be found in the Sitecore Search Scaling Guide.

Once the verification and setup is completed, reload your Sitecore instance and it should load properly. Cheers!

**Edited**: You may also want to check the SOLR support package DLL version against your current instance version. I experienced the issue several times this week and the root cause always boils down to DLL version discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

There is something we needed to do with this.  Have you changed from Lucene to Solr.  It's was in the Solr.config we needed to change some values, although I thought this bug had been fixed.  Take a look at

http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/01/21/sitecore-8-solr-configuration-and-setup/

https://born4joy.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/installation-and-configuration-of-solr-for-sitecore-8/

Comment: These all changes are incorporated, but still facing this issue.

Comment: Hi maybe worth looking at that as well https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897.  Are you using solr? Did you download the latest update packages from sitecore? It feels like a config is incorrect